# Handler.postDelayed and orientaton change issues

Tags: android, handler

I am facing a strange issue which I am not able to solve. The thing is, I have an activity and after pressing a button I change the visibility of some layouts. After that I am using a `Handler` in order to revert that situation after 4 seconds, and put everything as was before.

Everything works as expected except when I change the device orientation, if I change the device orientation during the process, my views will not be restored, I am not sure where the problem is :S.

Here is the relevant code

```
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private boolean mLogginIn = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_layout);

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mLogginIn = false;


    } else {

        mLogginIn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(getString(R.string.user_login_in),false);
        Log.d(TAG,"RESTORING MLOGIN IN = " + mLogginIn);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });

    if(mLogginIn)
        showProgress(true);
}
```

Now I present the relevant functions

```
//.......

public void attemptLogin() {

    showProgress(true);
    mMenu.findItem(R.id.started).setVisible(false);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showProgress(false);
                    Log.d(TAG,"MLOGGIN VALUE PROGRESS = " + mLogginIn);
                    mLogginIn = false;
                }
            });

        }
    },4000);
}
```

And `ShowProgress()`

```
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    mLogginIn = show;
    Log.d(TAG, "showProgress " + mLogginIn);

    int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
    .alpha(show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                    : View.GONE);
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                    : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

The most weird thing, is that when `onRestoreInstanceState` is called after the `postDelayed` code has been executed, `mLogginIn` shows the previous value (true), as if it had no effect at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `Activity` is recreated because of a configuration change, it is a completely different object instance, with another embedded view hierarchy. Your `Handler` is tight to the old object instance, and thus it modifies the old view hierarchy too. Therefore you don't see anything.

**Don't do this**: it leaks memory and might lead to crashes.

**Solution**:

1. When you post your `Runnable`, save the `Runnable` instance and the current timestamp in two references. If the `Runnable` runs normally, set the timestamp to -1 (within the `Runnable` code).
2. On `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` if the timestamp is different from -1, retain it across configuration changes and remove the runnable callbacks from the handler with `Handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)`.
3. When you recreate the activity restore the timestamp and calculate the difference with the current time. Post a new `Runnable` with the same logic with this delay (if it is 0 or negative you might want to run the runnable straight away instead of posting it). This `Runnable` is now tight to the new instance of `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand fhe problem. Just one question. What do yo mean by saving the runnable instance? Savingo unsing onsaveInstanceState? Or just hVing a reference in the class?.

Comment: Save it in a reference. You need the reference to remove the callbacks later on `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: The idea is the timestamp reference acts as a flag: non-negative = Runnable posted, negative = no Runnable posted. When the Runnable runs it clears the flag (negative). You can use this flag to safely save and restore state.

Answer (score 1):

When device orientation is changed your activity is destroyed and new one is created and state restored via savedInstanceState bundle. But your runnable you are posting with postDelayed is an anonymous inner class tied to original activity. This activity object is still around and your runnable modifies it, but it is no longer visible.

Your current architecture does not work, you have to choose another to achieve what you want.